# Проблема с решением функции произведение П

Tags: python, рекурсия, return

```
def P (j):
    P = 1
    for j in range(1, k+1):
11.      P*=((j-5)/(j-2))
   return P
14. print(P(j))
```

Ошибки:

line 14, in 
print(P(1))

line 11, in P

P*=((j-5)/(j-2))

ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

Не могу понять проблему

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 1) В вашем коде нет столько строк сколько указано в ошибках. 2) В вашем коде как минимум нет того кода который мог бы вызвать первую ошибку 3) последняя ошибка как бы говорит вам - в чем ваша ошибка, а именно - **на ноль делить нельзя** ```range = 2; j - 2= 0?```

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков Строчки указал(там программа немного больше, поэтому так). Насчёт ошибки с range, мне просто прописать в range 2?

Comment: Обратитесь к тому, кто задал эту задачу. Откуда мы знаем, что нужно делать при j равном 2. Кстати, если k будет 5 или больше, то результат будет равен 0.

Comment: @Эникейщик А как мне сделать так чтобы оно учитывало ОДЗ? По логике программа не должна работать при таких значениях